# Will jQuery .load() Work On PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery, cordova, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I know that the [jQuery .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a "problem": You can't retrieve pages that are outside of the current domain, because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but I remember when I was developing another program that I could do cross-domain AJAX without problems while on an PhoneGap compiled environment, but will it work while on PhoneGap(like normal AJAX) or it will just fail because of the policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.load()` or `$.ajax()` in PhoneGap applications. Most of my experience is with getting information from the same domain under which the app. is packaged. For example:

App. package identifier:

> com.my-domain.my-app

Website domain for ajax calls:

> www.my-domain.com

---

I just did a simple test in an iPhone emulator (via Xcode) and I was able to get the contents of a personal web domain as well as http://www.google.com/. Test was as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('http://www.google.com/', function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me and testing it **:)**

Comment: No problem, your question peaked my interest. If I find any more information regarding cross-domain ajax calls from native applications I'll post info/links here.

Comment: As far as I understand the reason for no cross-domain problems with PhoneGap is that the origin of the JS file is local filesystem - and for this source no additional restrictions are applied.

Comment: I also did the test and realized that it works, but the question remains why it works. It would be great if somebody could explain.

Comment: Additional info, Same origin policy also affects localhost and "file://" pages.

Comment: @TimBüthe My understanding is that the app on a device has no domain, so it has no method of checking if the request is on a different domain. Some platforms can set some jQuery settings to disallow cross-domain-access even though it's available: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing this, testing on the ipad simulator and it didnt work for me, I kept getting cross-domain ajax errors (i.e. permission errors).

I eventually found that I needed to Navigate to [projectName] -> Support Files -> phonegap.plist Under External Hosts add a new string with the value * Or add your exact domain

(From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810522/jquery-mobile-phonegap-on-iphone-fails-to-loadpage/8865778#8865778) thanks to Dror 'Yitzhakov).