# jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap on iphone fails to loadPage

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, cross-domain

I am trying to write a simple phonegap + jqm app that gets a page from remote server.

```
$.mobile.loadPage("http://mydomain.com/Mobile/MyPage.aspx")
          .done(function () { alert('done'); })
          .fail(function () { alert('fail'); });
 });
```

I set the following options:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

Added the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Everything works fine when I try it in desktop browsers (ff/chrome/safari) but it doesnt work on my iphone or in the iphone simulator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok it turned out to be something silly:

For cross domain request to work in iPhone (using phonegap and jquery mobile) you have to do the following:
In xCode:
Navigate to [projectName] -> Support Files -> phonegap.plist
Under External Hosts add a new string with the value *
Or add your exact domain

Comment: You don't need to set the `$.support.cors` or `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages` properties because your request is not originating from a domain, therefore cross-domain restrictions do not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it turned out to be something silly: For cross domain request to work in iPhone (using phonegap and jquery mobile) you have to do the following: In xCode: Navigate to [projectName] -> Support Files -> phonegap.plist Under External Hosts add a new string with the value * Or add your exact domain