# Parsing XML with Javascript (for eventual use in phonegap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm trying to parse some XML results in javascript to use with phonegap. As it stands my xml layout is:

```
<Results>
     <Result>
          <FirstName>John</FirstName>
          <Surname>Beech</Surname>
          <Company>CompanyName</Company>
          <Job_Title>Property Department</Job_Title>
          <UserID>184</UserID>
          <CompanyID>CompanyID</CompanyID>
          </Result>
     <Result>
          <FirstName>Rosie</FirstName>
          <Surname>Beech</Surname>
          <Company>CompanyName</Company>
          <Job_Title>Job Title</Job_Title>
          <UserID>10494</UserID>
          <CompanyID>17322</CompanyID>
     </Result>
</Results>
```

And I'm using the following javascript to at the moment just alert out the responses, but eventually I want to create a table of the responses.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Lookupbysurname.aspx?surname=beech',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {


                try {
                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = "false";
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    try {
                        parser = new DOMParser();
                        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert(e.message);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].childNodes[0].length; i++) {
                    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

However at the moment it's only alerting the same response out over and over. Have I put the loop together wrong? Loops in JS arent my forte! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, since you're already using jQuery, you can simplify your XML parsing logic and just use [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `parseXML()` by using `XMLHttpRequest`'s `responseXML` property, which is wrapped in jQuery as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Lookupbysurname.aspx?surname=beech',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xmlDoc) {
        alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].nodeValue);
    }
});
```

Since you're already using jQuery, you could use jQuery to traverse the XML:

```
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
$xml.find("CompanyID").each(function() {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Full code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Lookupbysurname.aspx?surname=beech',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xmlDoc) {
        var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('CompanyID').each(function() {
            alert( $(this).text() );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, where is xmlDoc defined in this? i'm getting an error that xmlDoc is not defined and that xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName is not a function - Tom

Comment: Sorry - Was being special, fixed the xmlDoc not defined, but still getElementsByTagName isnt working - http://paste.tiag.me/22 Tom

Comment: @TomBeech: Sorry, I meant that you need to put the second block of code in the `success` method. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> However at the moment it's only alerting the same response out over and over.

Of course it is, you're using the same index (`0`) each time.

But the TL;DR version of this is: Since you're already using jQuery, just use jQuery. You can not only use it to replace your complex parser creation logic by using [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead, but you can also use jQuery to do the loop. Here I assume you're trying to loop over `CompanyID` elements:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
$xml.find("CompanyID").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/unewum) | [source](http://jsbin.com/unewum/edit)

---

Building up to that, your code is using `0` rather than `i`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].childNodes[0].length; i++) {
    // This is always 0 -----------------------------------------v 
    alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

You want to use `i`, not `0`, if you want to loop over the child nodes.

---

But that loop is *hugely* inefficient, because you're going back and repeating the lookup each time. Instead:

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    alert(nodes[i].nodeValue);
}
```

Or alternately, of course, use `firstChild` and `nextSibling`:

```
var node;
for (node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID")[0].firstChild;
     node;
     node = node.nextSibling) {
    alert(node.nodeValue);
}
```

---

But looking at your XML, I suspect you want to loop over `CompanyID` nodes, rather than the child nodes of them:

```
var node;
for (node = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CompanyID");
     node;
     node = node.nextSibling) {
    alert(node.firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

---

But again, you can do this with dramatically less code by making more use of the library you're already using. :-)

Comment: You should also use `nodes[i]` instead of `nodes[0]` (second last box)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Will it work cross domain? Js will be local to the phone and XML on remote server

Comment: @TomBeech: The XML part is unrelated to domains; we've picked up at the point where you have the XML text in `data`. (And actually, you may not even need the `parseXML` call; if the server returns the correct MIME type, jQuery will parse it for you before giving it to the callback.) It's the `ajax` calls you need to worry about. My impression, based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154988) and some Googling, is that normally you're fine, but I haven't used PhoneGap myself.